# How to create and access global variables in MATLAB workspace while using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matlab, matlab-compiler

Consider the following case:

A main python file calls three different MATLAB functions -- `func_initialize.m`, `func_1.m` and `func_2.m`.

`func_initialize` take some arguments from the Python workspace, and creates a list of global variables: `aa`, `bb` and `cc`. These variables are then used in `func_1` and `func_2`.

`func_initialize` is structured as follows:

```
function func_initialize(args)
% Do some calculations using args
global aa bb cc
% Set values of aa bb and cc
end
```

However, within the python script, when I call these functions from the workspace dictionary:

```
import matlab.engine
eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab()
eng.workspace['aa']
```

it gives me the following error:

> MatlabExecutionError:    File
>   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2019a/toolbox/matlab/external/engines/engine_api/+matlab/+internal/+engine/getVariable.m,
>   line 27, in getVariable Undefined variable 'aa'.

What's wrong with the programming logic? Could there be a better way to share data between the three MATLAB files?

In my actual code, a Python object has some methods which call these three MATLAB functions. MATLAB engine is started by the class constructor. Then the class methods use this MATLAB engine to call various functions and access the variable names.

Comment: I believe you first have to declare these variables as global in the base workspace as well, e.g. by calling `global aa bb cc;` in a startup script. Otherwise, you could define some global variable 'getter' as described in the [docs of `global`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/global.html#description). Other option is to use [`assignin`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/assignin.html) to assign the variables in the base workspace. But perhaps it is best to put the variables in a struct, and have this as an input and output argument, thus completely avoiding globals.

Comment: Global variable getter function actually did the job for me. Passing structures seems a bit complicated between Python and MATLAB.

You can add it as an answer and I can accept it.